# pandas dataframe create new columns and fill values by using the values of the first column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df`, which has only one column `col`. I want to loop values of `col`, and add columns to fill values by using the values of the first column `col`. For example, the first row is a list, which has 3 elements `['text1','text2','text3']`. I want to add 3 columns, and fill values using `'text1'`,`'text2'` and `'text3'`.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'col':[['text1','text2','text3'],['mext1','mext2'],['cext1']]})
df

    col
0   [text1, text2, text3]
1   [mext1, mext2]
2   [cext1]
```

I want like this:

```
    col                     col_1     col_2     col_3
0   [text1, text2, text3]   text1     text2     text3
1   [mext1, mext2]          mext1     mext2     Nan
2   [cext1]                 cext1     Nan       Nan
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could construct a new dataframe by converting the values present in the single column  to it's `list` representation form. The elements of the `list` would now become separate column entities in itself.

These could then be concatenated with the original `DF` columnwise (`axis=1)`.

```
df_expand = pd.DataFrame(df['col'].tolist(), df.index)
df_expand.columns = df_expand.columns + 1
pd.concat([df['col'], df_expand.add_prefix('col_')], axis=1)
```

[image]

To get `None` to be represented as `NaN`, you could add `.replace({None:np.NaN})` at the end of the last syntax.

Comment: Does not work for `df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[['text1','text2','text3'],['mext1','mext2'],['cext1'],['cext2']]})`. Problem: `np.arange(1, df.shape[0] + 1)`.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution with `DataFrame` constructor, where need `rename` columns and [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
print (pd.DataFrame(df.col.values.tolist(), index=df.col)
         .rename(columns = lambda x: x+1)
         .add_prefix('col_')
         .reset_index())

                     col  col_1  col_2  col_3
0  [text1, text2, text3]  text1  text2  text3
1         [mext1, mext2]  mext1  mext2   None
2                [cext1]  cext1   None   None
```

Solution where find [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.max.html) length of list in column `col` by [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
cols = df.col.str.len().max() + 1
print (cols)
4
print (pd.DataFrame(df.col.values.tolist(), index=df.col,columns = np.arange(1, cols))
         .add_prefix('col_')
         .reset_index())
                     col  col_1  col_2  col_3
0  [text1, text2, text3]  text1  text2  text3
1         [mext1, mext2]  mext1  mext2   None
2                [cext1]  cext1   None   None
```